# SQL cumulative columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query to make an insurance paid loss triangle. I made a table with a column for a the date of loss and then multiple columns for the total payment checks sent out during x month after the date of loss. The thing about loss triangles is they need to be cumulative from left to right. Is there a cleaner way to do this? Thanks!

```
select
[Date of loss month],
--The following shows the cumulative paid development of losses by months old
[Payments after 0 months]=[0],
[Payments after 1 months]=[0]+[1],
[payments after 2 months]=[0]+[1]+[2],

[3]=[0]+[1]+[2]+[3],
[4]=[0]+[1]+[2]+[3]+[4],
[5]=[0]+[1]+[2]+[3]+[4]+[5],
[6]=[0]+[1]+[2]+[3]+[4]+[5]+[6],

--...Need it to go out to 120 months.
```

Comment: There is not an easier way to do this, although I've often done the calculation in a spreadsheet.

Comment: I think your first fault was that you pivoted your sumarised data. It would be much easier if you had left the summarised data unpivoted. Now, yes, your option is to do what you have done.

Comment: what is [0], [1], etc? will your table have 120 + 120 columns?

Comment: Pivot the columns, then do a range join (with between) to aggregate and sum payments.

Comment: Is there actually a difference / variance in the columns? If not, you can just multiply them out easily. For instance, a column of `[base payment]` or something, `[base payment] * 1 AS [Month 1]` AND `[base payment] * 2 AS [Month 2]`. And that sort of string building is easy in a spreadsheet, as @GordonLinoff mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this example. It unpivots and pivots the data. I've only written columns from 0 to 10, you can easily add the rest.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PaymentsSummary') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #PaymentsSummary

CREATE TABLE #PaymentsSummary (
    Date DATE,
    [0] INT,
    [1] INT,
    [2] INT,
    [3] INT,
    [4] INT,
    [5] INT,
    [6] INT,
    [7] INT,
    [8] INT,
    [9] INT,
    [10] INT)

INSERT INTO #PaymentsSummary
VALUES
    ('2018-06-10', 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10),
    ('2018-06-11', 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100)

DECLARE @StartRange INT = 0
DECLARE @EndRange INT = 10

;WITH Ranges AS
(
    SELECT
        StartRange = @StartRange,
        EndRange = @StartRange

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        StartRange = R.StartRange,
        EndRange = R.EndRange + 1
    FROM
        Ranges AS R
    WHERE
        R.EndRange < @EndRange
),
UnpivotedSummary AS
(
    SELECT
        P.Date,
        P.MonthNumber,
        P.Value
    FROM
        #PaymentsSummary AS S
        UNPIVOT (
            Value FOR MonthNumber IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])
        ) AS P
),
RangeTotals AS
(
    SELECT
        P.Date,
        C.EndRange,
        TotalValue = SUM(P.Value)
    FROM
        Ranges AS C
        INNER JOIN UnpivotedSummary AS P ON P.MonthNumber BETWEEN C.StartRange AND C.EndRange
    GROUP BY
        P.Date,
        C.EndRange
)
SELECT
    P.*
FROM
    RangeTotals AS R
    PIVOT (
        MAX(R.TotalValue) FOR R.EndRange IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])
    ) AS P
```

I highly suggest you change your table's structure to store the data by payment (just 1 payment!) and not already pivoted or stack together.